# Json producer in kafka-python

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying a simple kafka producer first time which will take data from json file record by record.
But I am getting error.

My Json File(test.json):

```
{
  "states": 
  [
    {
      "name": "Alabama",
      "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alaska",
      "abbreviation": "AK"
    }
  ]
}
```

My producer class:

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
print('Producer created..............')

with open('/home/ravi/test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for state in data['states']:
        producer.send('ECJson', json.dump(state))
```

But I am getting error:

```
Producer created..............
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prodECJson.py", line 10, in <module>
    producer.send('ECJson', json.dump(state))
TypeError: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.dump` will write on disk. What you want is `json.dumps` that will create a string from the given object. The [send](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html#kafka.KafkaProducer.send) function of KafkaProducer expects bytes so you have to encode the string too. You can also specify the serializer in the KafkaProducer object directly.

For example:

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', 
                         value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode("utf-8"))
print('Producer created..............')

with open('/home/ravi/test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for state in data['states']:
        producer.send('ECJson', state)
```